# How to handle exceptions from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm calling method `url_for` of gem `aws-s3`, and it throws a `MissingCredentialsError < StandardError`. How can I rescue it from the class where `url_for` is called? I know the solution for the missing credentials problem, but I would like to know how I could handle the exception. Tried this and no luck:

```
begin
  ... code that get the error...
rescue MissingCredentialsError
  a = "THIS IS AN ERROR"
end
```

when I run my tests it bumps in this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant Receipt::MissingCredentialsError
```

Comment: The correct response depends on context, such as how critical to your code's function it is that the `url_for` succeeded. It could be anything from printing a useful error message and exiting, to ignoring the error and continuing a loop of multiple requests as if nothing was wrong

Comment: How does it not work? Your code should capture the exception.

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to put the error there. edited and added

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore error and continue with rest of the script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924901/how-to-ignore-error-and-continue-with-rest-of-the-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be more specific when catching an error:

```
begin
  # code that get the error
rescue AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError => e
  # code that handles the exception
end
```

Comment: yes that was the problem... I'm very new to ruby.
gosh newbies right?
Thanx